# EDITING RC.LOCAL for NZBGet and Sickrage at startup on OSMC

Tags: boot, services, raspbian-jessie

```
    #!/bin/sh -e
    #
    # rc.local
    #
    # This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
    # Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
    # value on error.
    #
    # In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
    # bits.
    #
    # By default this script does nothing.

    sudo service nzbget start
    sudo service sickrage start

    exit 0
```

Is this code ok? What else do I need to have to restart the Pi2 and have the services start at boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

nzbget -D
python /opt/sickrage/SickBeard.py -d

exit 0
```

This is the file at `/etc/rc.local` that gets both services running at boot

Answer (score 1):

If they have init service files (which is the only way that will work -- I presume you've tried `sudo service ______ start` and it does), then you should just enable them.  First check:

```
grep Required-Start /etc/init.d/nzbget
```

You should get something like `S 2 3 4 5`, in which case you can just:

```
update-rc.d enable S 2
```

There maybe a bit of a complication if you are using systemd with jessie (it does by default), although I believe it still supports the older methodology.

Or you could just stick with what you have, which should work.  You should be able to check post boot w/ `service nzbget status`.

Comment: osmc@osmc:~$ service nzbget status  
* nzbget.service  
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)  
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: The same for Sickrage. I really don't want to restart until I know I can get the services back up?

Comment: Apparently the services don't exist.  Just because you have a program installed doesn't mean it came with Debian's spin on [SysV style init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SysV-style) scripts.  You can read more about that in `/etc/init.d/README`, but if what you want to do is run those programs at boot, the easiest thing to do would be to just start them with *the command you normally use* in `rc.local` -- except you don't need sudo, because it runs root.  Also, if that command blocks (i.e. does not go into the background), you need to follow it with `&` to put it in the background.

Comment: Using the full path and redirecting the output so you can debug problems is also a good idea, so, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/nzbget &> /tmp/nzbget.log &`.  The `&>` redirects any output.

Comment: Hmmm -> http://nzbget.net/Command_line_reference Try `which nzbget` for the path.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/nzbget for the filepath, the same command didn't return anything for Sickrage

Comment: Where's the instructions you followed to install sickrage?

Comment: http://www.htpcguides.com/install-sickrage-raspberry-pi-usenet-torrent-tv/

Comment: Minus the whole 'upstart' issue from another post you helped me on

Comment: Okay, looks like you are suppose to use `python /opt/sickrage/SickBeard.py -d`.  The `-d` is probably for ["daemon"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)), meaning it forks into the background so you should not need `&`, or `&> /tmp/...` for logging (it either has it's own log, or uses syslog.  They have [a forum](https://sickrage.tv/), BTW.

Comment: I'll try them both and get back to you once I'm home in about 3 hours

Comment: I have posted my final script below, it now works.